# After triangulation in Structure from Motion

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, point-cloud-library

I am working on Structure from Motion. I have did the following steps till now,

1. Feature Matching
2. Fundamental Matrix
3. Essential Matrix
4. Camera Matrix P
5. From triangulation, I got Point3d type values for all the matched features. I stored this in pointcloud variable.

I hope, I did right but from here I am confused to proceed further. What I have to do next ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your computations are correct up this point you are done for two views.

From now on you have multiple ways to improve your reconstruction:

1. Optimization (Bundle Adjustment) is very common although you have only two views (with camera parameters), the matched point correspondences and their 3D points.
2. Compute a dense point cloud, e.g. using [cmvs](http://www.di.ens.fr/cmvs/) or [incremental computation](http://viscg.uni-muenster.de/publications/2013/RJ13/wdia13.pdf)
3. Add more views with further point correspondences (or tracks) between the images. To do this you can use one of the solutions for the [Perspective-n-Point problem](http://www2.maths.lth.se/vision/publdb/reports/pdf/zheng-kuang-etal-iiccvi-13.pdf). As far as I know is the supposed method (P3P) in the RANSAC paper very common. For further information see the original [RANSAC paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~belhumeur/courses/compPhoto/ransac.pdf) or information from [Changchang Wu](http://ccwu.me/vsfm/vsfm.pdf).

For the last point it is very important to optimize the points and the camera parameter to get a good solution for the next view that is been added. Otherwise you will see drifts occuring in your reconstruction.